# ¿Para qué nos sirve AJAX y JQuery a la hora de enviar datos a una base de datos a través de PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, jquery, ajax

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#boton').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let datos=$('#formul').serialize();
        //Resto del código
    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"guia.php",
      data:datos,
      success:function(r){
        if (r==1) {
          alert('agregado con éxito');
        }else{
          alert('fallo del servidor');
        }
      }
    })
    return false;
  })
});
```

```css
<?php
include "conexion.php";
$nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
$enviar= "INSERT INTO formularios(nombre) VALUES('$nombre')";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $enviar);
?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="funcionalidad.js"></script>
  <form method="post" id="formul">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Formulario de inicio</legend>
    <input type="text" name="nombre">
    <button id="boton"></button>
  </fieldset>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

He visto vídeos, leído diversos artículos en los cuales se explica el funcionamiento de `AJAX` y `JQuery`, pero ando con un enredo en la cabeza, algo de locos. No entiendo que es lo que hace `AJAX` con exactitud, he entendido que es `JAVASCRIPT`, este toma los datos que se ingresan en un formulario y a través de la estructura que tiene envía los datos a el servidor. No entiendo si tengo que tomar los valores del formulario en `JAVASCRIPT` o en `PHP`. Lo que estaba intentando hacer es simple:

> - Enviar lo que el usuario escribía en un formulario a una base de datos, lo conseguí mediante `HTML` y `PHP`, pero después leí que esto se podía hacer sin que la página se recargara, comencé a investigar como se hacía y descubrí que era con `AJAX`, ahora ya no se hacía solo con `HTML` y `PHP`, ahora se incluía `JAVASCRIPT`. Cuando se incluye `JQuery` ya ni te cuento, ahí si quedo perdido, entiendo que es un fichero pero no entiendo cual es la labor que realiza en nuestro código, no entiendo si reemplaza el `AJAX` o qué hace. Me ayudaría mucho si me pueden hacer un ejemplo simple de como se envía 1 dato de un formulario utilizando `AJAX`, `JQuery`, `PHP`, `Mysql`.

```js
let boton=document.getELementById("boton");
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(boton).click(function(){
  let datos=$('formul').serialize();
  $.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   url:"guia.php",
   data:datos,
   success:function(r){
    if (r==1) {
     alert('agregado con éxito');
    }else{
     alert('fallo del servidor');
    }
   }
  })
  return false;
 })
});
```

```css
<?php
include "conexion.php";
$nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
$enviar= "INSERT INTO formularios(nombre) VALUES('$nombre')";
echo mysqli_query($conexion, $enviar);
?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <script src="funcionalidad.js"></script>

 <form method="post" id="formul">
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Formulario de inicio</legend>
  <input type="text" name="nombre">
  <input type="submit" id="boton">
 </fieldset>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Te falta el # del selector $('#formul').serialize();

Comment: Le agregué el "#" y aún así no llegan los registros a la base de datos

Comment: Bueno para que entres un poquito en contexto, Ajax es una técnica como ya lo dices para consumir un servicio en php sin necesidad de que se recargue la pagina, Ajax es esa comunicación que tienes entre el servidor y el cliente que se ejecuta en segundo plano trayendo una respuesta inmediata, y esa respuesta se da por medio de un `echo` o una impresión en pantalla como tal, por lo tanto, sí el script de php falla y eso te genera el error, Ajax también lo coge como una respuesta, el toma el texto plano que se genera en dicho archivo

Comment: Creo que en esta línea también te falta el Símbolo de # para obtener el formulario datos=$('formul').serialize()

Comment: Jquery es una librería que simplemente ayuda que sea más simple utilizar y codificar Javascript, simplificando así las cosas que haces con Javascript nativo, entonces tomando esto en cuenta, lo que te dicen arriba del **#** es para que el selector detecte que estás refiriendote a un **id**, entonces cuando haces esto: `$("#formul")` estás diciendo que busque un elemento en tu html que tenga como id "formul", te recomiendo [jQuery Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp) para que te familiarices más con ese tema

Comment: @CamiloCaroxh, además de lo ya señalado por otros miembros, el problema es que no estas haciendo nada para evitar que se envíe el formulario y se recargue la página. Te recomiendo cambiar el `<input type="submit" id="boton">` a tipo botón, es decir `<input type="button" id="boton">`, de esa forma vas a evitar fácilmente que se envíe el formulario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Efectivamente, la mejor opción que existe hasta ahora para comunicar datos entre el cliente (HTML-Javascript)  y el servidor (PHP-Base de datos), es Ajax. Porque, entre otras ventajas, permite llevar y traer datos entre cliente y servidor sin recargar la página, pudiendo actualizar cualquier cosa en el cliente o en el servidor. Para decirlo con una frase, Ajax es como una pasarela de datos entre cliente y servidor.

jQuery es una librería de Javascript, que tiene una sintaxis particular. Por ejemplo, jQuery usa mucho este signo `$` para referirse a los elementos, y tiene formas particulares para alcanzar los elementos, por ejemplo, para alcanzar un elemento por su `id`, jQuery usa el símbolo `#` seguido del id del elemento.

jQuery es una librería amplísima, con la cual puedes hacer casi todo lo que hace Javascript, quizá por eso mucha gente confunde a jQuery con Javascript. Pero a pesar de su *amplitud*  no deja de ser una librería, y para usarla debes incluir el archivo. Javascript por el contrario es nativo, viene con el navegador.

Creo que esto aclara un poco las dudas que planteas. Ahora con respecto a tu código, vamos a hacer que la petición funcione y a explicar algunas cosas más de paso.

Esta declaración es Javascript puro:

```
let boton=document.getELementById("boton");
```

Pero jQuery no te reconocerá ese elemento aquí:

```
$(boton).click(function(){
```

Porque la sintaxis de jQuery es diferente. Para que lo reconozca así, tendrías que ponerle el signo `$` en la declaración:

```
let $boton=document.getELementById("boton");
```

Y aquí:

```
$boton.click(function(){
```

Pero, no hay por qué complicarse. Para este caso no conviene mezclar. Usa en todo la sintaxis de jQuery. De entrada, si sólo quieres escuchar los clicks del botón, no necesitas declararlo como variable. Haz simplemente esto:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#boton').click(function(){
        let datos=$('#formul').serialize();
```

Ahí alcanzará el botón por su id. De paso, corregimos también lo del formulario, que tampoco estaba siendo alcanzando por su id al faltarle `#` delante.

**Pero** falta algo muy importante para que la página no se recargue, lo cual hace perder la gracia que tiene Ajax. Esto se logra  poniendo esta línea dentro de la función que escuchará el envío del formulario:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

El código quedaría entonces así:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#boton').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let datos=$('#formul').serialize();
        //Resto del código
```

Ajax enviará lo que estás pasando en la variable `datos` al servidor y dentro del `success` te traerá en la variable `r` lo que el servidor haya respondido. Esto puede ser un HTML, un text, un JSON, etc. En el código PHP tú haces `echo` del resultado de `query`, pero esto devuelve `TRUE` o `FALSE`. Deberías quizá verificar si se insertaron filas y mandar un mensaje del tipo "Se insertaron `n` filas".

Ya está, con esas correcciones, tu código debería funcionar. Si la página se sigue recargando, cambia el input de envío por esto:

```
<button id="boton">Enviar</button>
```

Intenta haciendo esos cambios y si sigue sin funcionar dilo en comentarios. Si queda alguna duda también.

Espero te ayude a aclarar conceptos.

---

## Código completo

Te dejo un código completo, he implementado algunos cambios en las diversas partes, aplicando varias recomendaciones que sería largo de explicar al detalle. Si no entiendes algo pregunta, de todos modos iré comentando los cambios principales dentro del mismo código.

#### HTML, Javascript/jQuery

Primeramente, usa una versión actualizada de la librería jQuery

```
<!-- Usar una versión reciente de jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Este es el código que manejará el envío de datos al servidor

```
/* Se recomienda function() en lugar de document.ready */   
$(function() {  
    $( "#boton" ).click(function( e ) {
        /* Evita que la página se recargue */
        e.preventDefault();
        let datos=$('#formul').serialize();
        var url='guia.php';
        /*Creamos una variable, sólo por motivos de claridad*/
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: url,        /*Debe apuntar a la ruta exacta del archivo PHP*/
            method: "POST",  /*Aquí en código viejo se usaba type, debe usarse method*/
            data: datos,
            dataType: "json" /* Indica el tipo de dato que responderá el servidor */
        });

        /*Cuando la petición sea exitosa*/
        request.done(function(r) {
            console.log(r); /*Una simple prueba, borrarlo cuando todo funcione*/

            /*Aquí se verifica si hubo algún fallo en el servidor, buscando la clave fail en el JSON*/
            if (r.fail) {
                console.log (`ERROR! ${r.fail}`); /*Se puede actualizar el DOM*/
            } else {
                /*Si no hubo fallo, todo fue OK. Aquí pueden venir más datos, aparte de la clave done*/
                console.log (`OK! ${r.done}`);   /*Se puede actualizar el DOM*/
            }
        });

        /*Cuando la petición falle*/
        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            /*En vez de un alert, se puede poner algo en un elemento del DOM*/
            alert(`La petición falló ${textStatus}`);
        });
    });
});
```

Este es el formulario, aquí no hay cambio:

```
<form method="post" id="formul">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Formulario de inicio</legend>
    <input type="text" name="nombre">
    <input type="submit" id="boton">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

### PHP

Se ha creado un código totalmente controlado. Esto es imprescindible en la peticiones Ajax. El cliente espera una respuesta del servidor y por tanto debes controlar todo lo que pasa en el código, guardarlo en alguna parte y dar una respuesta adecuada.

Aquí se crea un array llamado `$mData` al cual le iremos agregando sea una clave `fail`, sea una clave `done`, según ocurra algún error o no, poniendo dentro el mensaje de error.

Si observas la petición Ajax más arriba, verás que en la respuesta hay un `if (r.fail)` que evaluará el JSON que respondió el servidor. He optado por responder un JSON porque es lo habitual, y porque permite mandar al cliente un objeto organizado, con claves/valores, para que haya un criterio claro a la hora de manejar la respuesta.

Otro parche importante que he añadido ha sido usar consultas preparadas para insertar el dato. Tu código actual es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*. Cuando puedas infórmate sobre ese tema, porque atañe seriamente a la seguridad de los datos y del sistema.

Otro aspecto **MUY IMPORTANTE** en tu código de servidor es que cuides bien lo que sale por pantalla con `echo, print` o con bloques HTML. Debe haber una sola salida por pantalla, que en este caso será el JSON, al final de todo.

```
#Recogerá lo ocurrido a lo largo del código
$mData=array();

#Verificamos si se posteó un valor para el nombre y lo guardamos
$mName=!empty($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : NULL;

#Si no hay valor irá al último else
if ($mName) {
    #Sólo aquí requerimos la conexión
    require "conexion.php";
    #Verificamos si la conexión es válida
    if($conexion) {
        #Usamos consultas preparadas, para evitar Inyeccion SQL
        $sql="INSERT INTO formularios(nombre) VALUES (?)";
        #Verificamos que la consulta no sea errónea
        if ( $stmt=$conexion->prepare($sql) ) {
            #Pasamos el dato
            $stmt->bind_param("s",$mName);
            #Verificamos que no haya más errores, como clave duplicada en la BD, por ejemplo
            if ( $stmt->execute() ) {
                $mData["done"]="Se insertaron {$stmt->affected_rows} filas";
            } else {
                #Nótese que aquí se busca el error en $stmt
                $mData["fail"]=$stmt->error;
            }
        } else {
            $mData["fail"]=$conexion->error;
        }
    }else{
        $mData["fail"]="No hay conexión activa, revise las credenciales o la base de datos";
    }
} else {
    $mData["fail"]="No se postearon los datos. Revise el formulario o el código Javascript";
}

#El header es muy importante para estos casos
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
#Respondemos al cliente. OJO, esto es lo único que debe salir por pantalla
echo json_encode($mData);
```

Comment: No se si hay una errata en lo que has escrito o no lo he entendido yo bien ya que parece que dices que `let boton=document.getElementById("boton")` es distinto de `let $boton=document.getElementById("boton")`. Realmente es guardar el resultado de la misma función en variables con diferente nombre. Lo que si que sería distinto sería `let boton=$(document.getElementById("boton"))` o más fácilmente `let boton = $("#boton")` ya que ahi si que estaríamos recibiendo un objeto de jQuery, mientras que en los otros casos lo que se recibe es un objeto Element.

Comment: @ordago no comprobé esa parte, pero, si mal no recuerdo, si no le pones `$` delante luego no puedes usar el elemento con código en sintaxis jQuery. Es lo que recuerdo en algunos casos en los que quería declarar el elemento para luego cambiarlo mediante `prop` o `attr`

Comment: Hice los cambios que me sugeriste y sigue sin funcionar, no llegan los datos a la base de datos.

Comment: ¿El archivo `guia.php` y el script donde tienes el código Ajax están en el mismo directorio? Para que los datos lleguen, debes poner la dirección correcta. Si lo pones así: `url:"guia.php"` se entiende que ambos archivos se encuentran en el mismo directorio. ¿Es así @CamiloCaroxh?

Comment: Mira, puse la imagen, todos los archivos están en una carpeta, además de esto subí una imagen con la base de datos.

Comment: @CamiloCaroxh ok, vamos a mejorar un poco la petición Ajax y el código PHP, agregando funciones de manejo de error. Ahora edito la respuesta y te aviso.

Comment: @CamiloCaroxh otra cosa, en la imagen no veo la extensión `.js` de tu archivo `funcionalidad` ¿?

Comment: Ni idea, siempre que guardo los archivos creados en sublimetext aparecen de ese modo.

Comment: @CamiloCaroxh al final de la respuesta hay una sección titulada **Código completo** donde he puesto cómo debería quedar todo. Modifica tanto el código Javascript como el código PHP exactamente de ese modo y debería funcionar. Activa la consola para que veas los resultados en ella. He probado el código y funcionar perfectamente. Si hay algún error me dices. Saludos.